# Can you use Dynamic Time Warping (DTW) Or Other Timeseries Alignment Techniques on Event Sequence Data?

Tags: python, time-series

I have a dataset of around 80 000 event sequences.

Each sequence is a list of events occuring at timestep t.

```
example_sequences = [['Start Event','Event 1','Event 5','Event 4]
                     ['Start Event','Event 1', 'Event 7', 'Event 4','Event 3']]
```

The length of the sequences varies between ~ 10-20 events.

As a preprocessing step I would want to align these sequences before training a neural network for anomaly detection (I'm using Python here).

Any tips on libraries, github repos, blog posts or similar for event sequence alignment would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use sequence alignment algo like dynamic time warping on sequences of strings. You must first convert them into numeric sequences. One easy way would be to map them using a dict.

```
example_sequences = [['Start Event','Event 1','Event 5','Event 4'],
                     ['Start Event','Event 1', 'Event 7', 'Event 4','Event 3']]

m = {
    'Start Event':0,
    'Event 1':1,
    'Event 2':2,
    'Event 3':3,
    'Event 4':4,
    'Event 5':5,
    'Event 6':6,
    'Event 7':7,
}

num_sequences = [[m[item] for item in sublist] for sublist in example_sequences]
print(num_sequences)

[[0, 1, 5, 4], [0, 1, 7, 4, 3]]
```

Now you have numeric sequences and you can use sequence alignment methods on them.

Comment: Would it be possible to also apply on one-hot-encoded vectors? Because here I guess event 0 would be closer to 1 than to event 5? Which is not necessarily the case.

Comment: I am not sure one-hot-encoded arrays are the best input for DTW. You can experiment though. In general, you should have the domain knowledge to evaluate how to best translate the strings in numbers. The main point stays the same; you can use DTW on numeric sequences only, not on string ones.